# Update Data by getting Values from Name Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am attempting to update data through the use of arrays. The basis is that I have a table that looks as follows:

```
|| idtest || testfieldA || testfieldB || testfieldC || externalId ||
```

Where idtest is the primary key, and the external id is an id that correlates to another table's primary key, so perhaps data values for row idtest = 1, 2, and 3 coul all share the same external id.

hence my goal is to update data within it. The form element I have created is as shown below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test.test WHERE externalId = $callID";
$r = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

for ($tcount =1; $rowTest = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rtest); $tcount++){
    $idtest = $rowTicket['idtest'];
    $testfieldA = $rowTicket['testfieldA'];
    $testfieldB = $rowTicket['testfieldB'];
    $testfieldC = $rowTicket['testfieldC'];
    $externalid = $rowTicket['externalId'];
    echo "<div>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='idtest' value='$idtest'>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='testfieldA[$tcount]' value='$testfieldA'>";
        echo "<input type='number' step='0.01' min='0' name='testfieldB[$tcount]' value='$testfieldB'>";
        echo "<input type='number' name='testfieldC[$tcount]' value='$testfieldC'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='externalId' value='$externalid'>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Which will echo a form tag with name=name[e], for example  with an initial value of the return number. I also don't do the name=idtest[] for the idtest since it's unique every time anyway.

All of this works just fine, and it echoes what I want it to from the data when called on by an onclick function that links it to updatetest.php?callid=#. However, I now want to update the content. The system I'm trying is to call a while loop as follows:

```
$e = 0;
$more = TRUE;
$idtest = $_POST['idtest'];

while($more){
    if(isset($_POST['testfieldA'.$e]) && isset($_POST['testfieldB'.$e]) && isset($_POST['testfieldC'.$e])){
        $test1 = $_POST['testfieldA'.$e];
        $test1 = trim($test1);

        $test2 = $_POST['testfieldB'.$e];
        $test2 = trim($test2);

        $test3 = $_POST['testfieldC'.$e];
        $test3 = trim($test3);

        $sql = "UPDATE test.test SET testfieldA = ?, testfieldB = ?, testfieldC= ? WHERE idtest = ?";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssd", $test1, $test2, $test3, $idtest) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    } else {
        $more = FALSE;
    }
} 
$e++;
```

However, this does not run. What is an effective manner to loop through each name and get the number, and update the data as long as the name exists? Excuses by the way if this question seems unclear, I have a hard time phrasing it.

Comment: What is your expectation with `while` loop? you init `$e`, incrementing it outside `while` loop, but you check for `$l` (undefined?). But what utility have `$e`, `$l` and the `while` itself? `$_POST['testfield1'.$e]` = `$_POST['testfield10']`

Comment: that l is a misspell, and i need to edit the question a little bit, since i changed the table headings. In that case, while is the case for while more is true, with will become false when isset($_POST['testfieldA'.$e]) is not set or does not exist. $e also adds up each time, but like you pointed out this seems flawed. Let me update my question as well to update the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTML form write input(s) in this way:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='testfield1[]' value='$testfield1'>";
```

The array conversion is directly made submitting the form.

Then, processing data, write something like this:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $_POST['testfield1'] ); $i++ )
{
    $test1 = trim( $_POST['testfield1'][$i] );
    $test2 = trim( $_POST['testfield2'][$i] );
    (...)
}
```

Comment: This works by the way. I already had the input name='testfieldA[]', so the problem was never with the getting, more the updating and getting the loop right. Your loop system worked perfectly, thank you.